# How to set a SpannableString to an EditText in an Android Material TextInputLayout?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, material-components-android

I can't find a way to set the text of an `EditText` in a Material `TextInputLayout` to a `SpannableString` and have the styling actually show up on screen. I've tried every combination of `EditText` inside a `TextInputLayout`, e.g.:

1. `AppCompatEditText`
2. `EditText`
3. `TextInputEditText`

with every way to create a `SpannableString`, e.g.:

1. `HtmlCompat.fromHtml(string, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)`
2. `SpannableString(string).setSpan(...)`
3. `TextUtils.stringOrSpannedString(string)`

with every way to set the text of an `EditText`, e.g.:

1. `edittext.setText(spannedString)`
2. `edittext.setText(spannedString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)`
3. `edittext.append(spannedString)`

The crazy thing is they all work when the EditText is not inside a Material `TextInputLayout`, so it must be a problem with that. More information: the `SpannableString` is respected when you set the hint or placeholder text on the `TextInputLayout`, just not the text of the `EditText` inside it. I looked through the `TextInputLayout` source code, but didn't see anything wrong. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out right when I was going to give up. You can get the `Editable` object from the `EditText` and then apply the `Span` to it. Here's how:

```
mEditText.text.setSpan(...)
```

Surprisingly easy when you know where to look.

Comment: tried to setText(spanString) - no success  
but your solution worked for me  
thanks